# Can every file really own at least 2 names (and thus 2 hard links)?

Tags: linux, files, filenames, inode, hard-link

[This page on inodes](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Inodes.html) has been exceptional help in grasping the surface-level concept of file systems.  On the same page, the author has inserted this snippet demonstrating that each file or directory has at least 2 names (and hard links):

```
/tmp/junk$ ls -id ..
327681 ..
/tmp/junk$ cd ..
/tmp$ ls -id .
327681 .
```

We can see that `/tmp` has 3 hard links:

1. Presumably, an inode for the filename “tmp”
2. The same inode for the name “..”
3. The same inode for the name “.”

**My question: can the “junk” file in the `/tmp` directory also have 3 names (and hard links) if it is given a child directory? For example, `/tmp/junk/paper_balls`.**

My hypothesis: If the “junk” file becomes a parent, it can be invoked with `..` but relatively, meaning the current working directory (from which `..` is typed) would have to be within the directory path `/tmp/`. The answer to my question is probably too advanced.

Comment: Hard link count of a directory is not reliable. It's filesystem dependent. Technically, hard link count for any inode is meaningless, you don't need to care about it, it's simply a have-to for most filesystem to work.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I’m using the Stack Exchange app, and it’s pretty buggy. Really? I was starting to see magic. The second field in the result of `ls -l` tells you the hard link count. It may be relatively meaningless information, but it’s nice to be able to read command results like a name badge. I was thinking each inode created a hard link.

Comment: Can't you run a simple experiment to find out? `mkdir junk; cd junk; ls -lid .;mkdir foo; ls -lid .; mkdir bar; ls -lid .; mkdir baz; ls -lid .` should clarify what is happening.

Comment: Can't really understand your language.  Inode is just inode, a hard link is a name for it. You can create a inode without name

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1073803/295286

Comment: Also would like to point out this:"If the “junk” file becomes a parent..."  A file can't really become a "parent" in the sense of how directory has parent link in subdirectory. So if `/tmp/junk/parent` is a directory, there will be `/tmp/junk/parent/..` pointing back to `/tmp/junk`. Otherwise if you have `/tmp/junk/parent` that points to something like `/tmp/child` well, that's a regular hard link to file. Directories can't have hard links aside from `.` or `..` per POSIX specifications

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy so from following the links some of you shared, I learned that hard linking directories corrupts the filesystem, in that loops are made and the tree structure is compromised. I know I phrased some of my comments horribly. I should have known that files are usually dead-ends in directories.

Comment: @steven no worries, i'm glad you got the answers you were seeking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial number of hard links is 1 for a **file** and 2 for a **directory** (the first link is its name in the parent folder, and the second hard link is `.`). The link count for a directory goes up by one each time a subdirectory is created in it (due to `..` in each subdirectory).

This count can be easily viewed with `ls -l`. It is the second value. Take a look:

```
~/x$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 54 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 tomasz tomasz   19 Sep 23 18:45 1
-rw-r--r--  1 tomasz tomasz   19 Sep 23 18:45 2
~/x$ mkdir d
~/x$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 54 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 tomasz tomasz   19 Sep 23 18:45 1
-rw-r--r--  1 tomasz tomasz   19 Sep 23 18:45 2
drwxr-xr-x  2 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:11 d
~/x$ mkdir d/dd
~/x$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 54 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 tomasz tomasz   19 Sep 23 18:45 1
-rw-r--r--  1 tomasz tomasz   19 Sep 23 18:45 2
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomasz tomasz 4096 Sep 24 00:11 d
```

The second value for `d` went up from 2 to 3 after creating `d/dd` within it.

**See mosvy's comments below for a wider view.**

Comment: Oh, are hard links unique per directory path? So, if I run `ls -l` on two separate directory paths, will I get different values on the 2nd field? I need to start a shell session! The page I read from, which is linked above with the question, said, “Inodes are always unique, but unique per [disk] partition.”

Comment: @Steven They are underneath paths, and so the count should be the same wherever you count. See this about partitions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290525/why-are-hard-links-only-valid-within-the-same-filesystem

Comment: @Steven If you are interested with links then go as deep as you want. Otherwise, it's enough to remember there are some entities called inodes on which the files and directories are based. You'll meet them now and then but not so often. Possibly it's a better idea to start with symbolic links, which are more popular and higher level.

Comment: No. A directory can have a link count of __1__ (on filesystems where directories don't have _physical_ `.` and `..` entries, and where __its link count will stay 1 when subdirs are created__), or even __0__ (for a deleted directory which is still the cwd of some process or is still open from somewhere).

Comment: @mosvy Interesting. I've never met these systems. Can you give examples?

Comment: @Tomasz if you want an example of a hard-disk general-purpose fs, you can try __btrfs__. __tl;dr__ the link count for a directory doesn't mean anything, and unlike the existence of the `.` and `..` entries (which are just faked by most linux fs, even if they're not really required), the POSIX standard does not say anything about it.

Comment: @Tomasz if you're on debian like, this will set up everything `apt-get install btrfs-progs && truncate -s 3G /tmp/3G && mkfs.btrfs -f /tmp/3G && mkdir -p /tmp/btrfs && mount /tmp/3G /tmp/btrfs`  and you could then happy-testing inside `/tmp/btrfs` ;-)

Comment: @mosvy what do you mean by “physical?” And it appears that link count increments concurrently for the pointer and pointee upon link creation.

Comment: @Steven No it does not, there's no pointer and pointee in the way you see them. When you create a _hard_ link with `ln old new`, both `old` and `new` are directory entries pointing to the same file/inode, and the link count, permission, size and other metadata are properties of the file/inode, not of the directory entries; `new` does not point to `old` or vice-versa.

Comment: @Steven since you cannot create hard links to directories, on filesystems like btrfs (and many others) which do not use `.` or `..` directory entries (but only fake them in dir listings for POSIX compatibilty), the link count of a directory inode will stay __1__ throughout, no matter how many subdirs you create inside it.